# Is the Service Fabric service running on the primary node a stateful service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is the Service Fabric service running on the primary node itself a stateful service?

The reason for asking is capacity planning. Recommended is d3v2, but is doing with d2v2 more than enough for Primary with Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Standard_B2ms for our system nodes. You could probably go lower on the system nodes, they are not under heavy load anyway

Answer (score 0):

The Service Fabric system services that run on the primary node type are indeed stateful services. If you are doing capacity planning, I recommend you visit the following document which has our production readiness checklist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-production-readiness-checklist

For production workloads:

- It's recommended to dedicate your clusters primary NodeType to system services, and use placement constraints to deploy your application to secondary NodeTypes.
- The recommended VM SKU is Standard D3 or Standard D3_V2 or equivalent with a minimum of 14 GB of local SSD.
- The minimum supported use VM SKU is Standard D1 or Standard D1_V2 or equivalent with a minimum of 14 GB of local SSD.
- The 14 GB local SSD is a minimum requirement. Our recommendation is a minimum of 50 GB. For your workloads, especially when running Windows containers, larger disks are required.
- Partial core VM SKUs like Standard A0 are not supported for production workloads.
- Standard A1 SKU is not supported for production workloads for performance reasons.